# jquery how to filter a element from array value

Tags: jquery, filter

In my form i should apply two variety's of class based on the existence in array for that how do i filter?

this is my try:

```
<form>

    <input type="checkbox" value="one" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="two" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="three" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="four" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="five" />

</form>

var names = ["one","two","three"];


$(":checkbox", "form").filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() === names
}).addClass("blue")

$(":checkbox", "form").filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() !== names
}).addClass("green")
```

but not works.. any correct way to get it done

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGYWm/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check whether the input value exists in the array, not array names is equal to the value. For that you can use [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), it will return the index of the item if it finds it in the array else -1

```
$("form :checkbox").filter(function(){
    return $.inArray(this.value, names) > -1
}).addClass("blue")

$("form :checkbox").filter(function(){
    return $.inArray(this.value, names) == -1
}).addClass("green")
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4cyVY/)

Or

```
var names = ["one","two","three"];

$("form :checkbox").addClass(function(){
    return $.inArray(this.value, names) > -1 ? 'blue' : 'green'
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SD7QH/)

Comment: didn't downvote, but why not use `names.indexOf(this.value)`?

Comment: @JanDvorak support for IE < 9